# Databricks secrets

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I want to store a token and it's expiry time in Databricks scope. How to do that?
In documentation it was seen like either string type or byte type can be stored inside a scope. Also is there any way to encrypt the details stored

Comment: Might help: [Secret management | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are few approaches for that:

- You can create a JSON string out of the Python structure (dict or list) containing your token and expiration time, and store this string in the secret (via REST API or databricks-cli). And then decode JSON string back into that struct (assuming that you're using a dict with two fields "expiration" and "token"):

```py
import json

data = json.loads(dbutils.secrets.get(scope, secret))
token = data["token"]
expiration = data["expiration"]:
```

- store each value (token and expiration) as separate secrets.

The first method may also better work if you want to encrypt that data, but you still need to store the encryption key somewhere.